# Set `AfterClean` to csproj file generated by CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm generating MSBuild files (.csproj) using CMake.
At some time, I need to open the generated .csproj using Visual Studio, to do some debug and rebuild, etc...

I need my CMakeLists file to insert the following lines to the .csproj file:

```
  <Target Name="AfterClean">
    <Exec Command="..\my_clean_script.sh" />
  </Target>
```

So, my_clean_script.sh is executed when I clean the project from Visual Studio to clean some external dependencies files (not part of the project) created by my CMakeLists file.

Any way to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to use `file(APPEND <filename> <content>...)` ?
ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#writing ?

Comment: Nice workaround, but I actually need to "insert" the lines before `</Project>`, append won't work. I updated the question to clarify that.